# Fast implementation of SLSQP for python

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, blas, constraint-programming

I have a huge optimization problem with several thousand parameters. For smaller problems, I used SLSQP implemented in scipy, which works well for less than 2000 variables. However, it becomes very inefficient after that. I noticed that the optimization procedure uses only one virtual core instead of many. I have OpenBLAS installed on my machine, therefore, the typical matrix operations should utilize all cores. I suspect that implementation of SLSQP in scipy is very inefficient and do not use BLAS routines for that. I checked out the code in the Git repository and found function 'DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION ddot_sl(n,dx,incx,dy,incy)', which strengthen my concerns. 
Could you suggest a faster SLSQP implementation than in scipy?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of the internals of *slsqp*? I does not seem so. Some dot-implementation will not be the bottleneck of your calculation. Calculating the [bfgs-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) will be. And that will always cause trouble for so many variables. Therefore stuff like [l-bfgs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS) got invented! So... check your theory, think and maybe there is something which does not need to calculate the full-batch gradient!

Comment: [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Algorithms) modified the code from scipy (but kept the core) and writes the following in the docs: ```Note: Because the SLSQP code uses dense-matrix methods (ordinary BFGS, not low-storage BFGS), it requires O(n^2) storage and O(n^3) time in n dimensions, which makes it less practical for optimizing more than a few thousand parameters.``` which strengthens my comments above. Summary of your problem: it's the method / application; not the implementation.

Comment: Well, I was too rough, calling this implementation ‘very inefficient’. I just meant that it looks purely single threaded and cannot be improved by substituting BLAS. I am sure that using multithreaded matrix operations would be beneficial for that algorithm also (by a constant factor). BTW, I found that PyOpt has another implementation, but I haven’t tested it yet.

Comment: Often the original fortran-code is used in these algorithms used for decades (like this). It's often very costly to port these sources to some more modern approaches while keeping the quality (most of these algorithms are very highly tuned to handle numerical difficulties well). I'm not saying it can't be improved. But there is a reason, *a lot* of old fortran code is still there (and scipy chose these sources). The question in your case is just: is it the correct algorithm? Is there anything else working better? And that's hard to answer without specifics. (not sure if problem is sparse/ not)

Comment: PyOpt is using the same algorithm ([docs](http://www.pyopt.org/reference/optimizers.slsqp.html)) sharing the same complexity. (and of course using some very old slightly modified fortran-sources)

Comment: This algorithm is just not designed to handle large sparse problems. Some minor tweaking will achieve also just minor improvements. It is much better to switch to a solver that is actually designed to handle large sparse problems. Here are a few: SNOPT, IPOPT, KNITRO, CONOPT. Some of these solvers are easily called from Python using Pyomo. If your problem is large and dense things may become somewhat murkier (In that case I usually try large, sparse solvers and hope for the best)..

Comment: One problem is QP and another is a quadratically constrained problem. I can solve them with qp and socp solvers implemented in cvxopt. When QP scales well up to 10 thousand parameters (and can be solved very fast), the quadratically constrained problem yields some issues like 'domain error' exceptions, which I haven’t fixed yet. I suggested that I could brute force quadratically constrained problem with SLSQP. But it appeared to be too slow. Anyway, I want to find something more general than QP for some new problems. BTW, I found that GRG could be also used, but I cannot find an implementation

Comment: Did you use [ecos](https://www.embotech.com/ECOS) (probably default for SOCP)? Did you try [scs](https://github.com/cvxgrp/scs) which is also coming with cvxpy? It's very fast (at some accuracy-costs).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Can you recommend *pyomo*? While a implemented some stuff with it (different kind of problem-classes), i never liked the more classic approach of usage (looks more like an algebraic modelling system than the modern interfaces available for commercial-solvers). While i love the innumerable number of features, i also dislike the documentation a lot. Most stuff is only learned during reading the mailing-list. (It just seems, there is no competitive and free library available with this set of features; besides [JuMP](https://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) available in *julia*)

Comment: Thank you for all suggestions and advices! If PyOpt uses the same sources, I will not bother itegrating it. I will take a closer look at Pyomo instead. I haven't tried ecos and csc yet, looks like good things to try also.

Comment: @ChenGupta You probably used ecos, because it should be default and i won't expect good results. But if ecos is too slow, it might be valuable to try *scs* which is way faster (again: less accuracy). Of course it's still a very general algorithm, but worth a try (because you just need to use ```solver=SCS``` if you already got a cvxpy-implementation).

Comment: For large QP and SOCP problems also have a look at some state-of-the-art solvers like Gurobi, Cplex and Mosek. They tend to be faster than general purpose NLP solvers for these problems.